# Using a Date in Excel Formula without using VBA

Tags: excel, date, formula

I am trying to combine 4 formulas that work independently into one formula to provide information to users in regards to the status of a task in excel (this is all I have available to work with).

Cell B6: Project Due Date: 9/12/15

Cell B7: Document Received Date: would be filled in by user

The document must be received -150 days of the project due date

Formulas and result:

```
IF(AND(B6="",B7=""),"","")
```

This works

```
IF(AND(B6="",B7<>"",TODAY()=B7-150),"Due Today","")
```

This works

```
IF(AND(B6="",B7<>"",TODAY()>B7-150),"Overdue","")
```

This works

```
IF(AND(B6="",B7<>"",TODAY()>=B7-155,TODAY()<=B7-151),"Approaching Due Date","")
```

This works

```
=IF(B6<>"","Complete","")
```

This works

Unforunately I can't have 5 cells to determine status, so naturally I would like to combine them all into one cell and I just can't come up with the right formula.

This is what I have put together but I get #VALUE! error

> =IF(AND(B6="",B7=""),"",""),IF(AND(B6="",B7<>"",TODAY()=B7-150),"Due Today",""),IF(AND(B6="",B7<>"",TODAY()>B7-150),"Overdue",""),IF(AND(B6="",B7<>"",TODAY()>=B7-155,TODAY()<=B7-151),"Approaching Due Date",""),IF(B6<>"","Complete","")

Can someone help me catch what I'm missing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

when combining IF statements that you want to work in sequence, it's not a simple case of putting commas between each one.

If you are sure there will never be a case where more than one of the if statements will return something, then putting the ampersand '&' between each one would work.
[`&` is shorthand for `CONCATENATE()`]

If you are not sure, then you have to put the next if statement in place of the empty result.

Using the first 2 you have,

```
IF(AND(B6="",B7=""),"","")  
IF(AND(B6="",B7<>"",TODAY()=B7-150),"Due Today","")
```

We would get:

```
IF(AND(B6="",B7=""),"",IF(AND(B6="",B7<>"",TODAY()=B7-150),"Due Today",""))
```

You can repeat this for each of your formulas to produce a format that should really not see the light of day... There is the issue of Excel only allowing 7 <sub>*(*see comments)*,</sub> nested IF statements, so if you get more statuses, then you would reach that limit quickly.

assuming the formulas continue in sequence B8,B9,B10... you can hide the columns you use for the calculation, and put `=B8&B9&B10&B11&B12` into B13 – This will maintain readability, and as concatenate has no limit, you can add in an extra column if needed, and add another cell to the final cell.

Comment: @pnuts, perhaps, but that's a whole new level of headache when it comes to debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Pretty much using nested if statements, not pretty but it gets the job done.  This is assuming as you stated the Due date is in B6 and document received is in B7.

`=IF(B7="",IF(TODAY()=B6-150,"Due Today",IF(TODAY()>B6-150,"Overdue",IF(TODAY()>=B6-155,"Approaching Due Date","Still Have Time"))),"ERROR")`

Edit: added clarity and code tags.